# UITableviewCell GetCell is not being called

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac. I have a `UITableview` named **SchoolSchedule**. I am setting the `Source` from a button, but then when I click the button **GetCell** is not called, however, **RowsInSection** is called.
Here is my class:

```
 public class ScheduleTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private Schedule[] school;

    public ScheduleTableViewSource(Schedule[] school)
    {
        this.school = school;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (ScheduleCell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell_id", indexPath);
        var school1 = school[indexPath.Row];
        cell.Updatecell(school1);
        cell.TextLabel.Text = school[indexPath.Row].Site;
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return school.Length;
    }



}
```

here is my button code :

```
 partial void Get_button_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {

        bool check = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if(check)
        {

            Service1 client = new Service1();
            var school = client.CypressRidge("CypressRidge");
            SchoolSchedule.Source = new ScheduleTableViewSource(school);
            SchoolSchedule.ReloadData();

        }
        else{
            Console.Write("Error no Internet connection");
            return;
        }
     //   int stop =0;

    }
```

I have checked and there is data coming in from my service. so that is not the problem. can anyone help?

Comment: the getCell is not called because when you click a button, the method that is called is RowSelected in a UITableView. This is the method called when occur a selection or action in a specific cell in UITableView.

Comment: So do I have to override RowSelected ?

Comment: yes you need to override RowSelected

Comment: What number does the `RowsInSection` method return? are you sure your data is available before the `RowsInSection` call?

Comment: yes I use the debugger and I can see the data and it is return 25

Comment: RowSelected did not work. it too was not called

Comment: can anyone help ? I am not sure why this is not being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to deleted the table and make a new one.
there a bug in Xamarin.

Comment: How did you make it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to fix it setting up Identifier property of TableView first prototype row - in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

In addition to implementing the IUITableViewDelegate and IUITableViewDataSource interfaces in the .cs file, calling RegisterNibForCellReuse, and assigning the table view's EstimatedRowHeight, it's easy to forget to set the data source and delegate properties of the table view in the XIB.

[image: Xcode screenshot]